Como hago para que en cypress 13 me tome los json que tengo en la carpeta de environment?
En cypress 12, dentro de la carpeta environmments tenia jsons varios donde tenia varias urls de diversos endpoints según ambiente de prueba; el mismo lo levantaba con npx cypress open --env environment=ambiente donde quiera probar
Se me actualizo a cypress 13 y ahora cuando ejecuto la misma sentencia, me da error
cy.request() failed trying to load:
http://cypress.env().urldeprueba1.url/
We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.
We received this error at the network level:

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cypress.env().urldeprueba1.url


The request we sent was:
Method: GET
URL: http://cypress.env().urldeprueba1.url/
Como tengo que hacer para que pueda usar esos Json?
